# Loading an AGOL map with a token in ArcGIS 100.*

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-ios

I am trying to upgrade from ArcGIS 10.* to the new 100.* framework and I am having trouble getting the secured map to load. This is the old code:

```
_credential = [[AGSCredential alloc]initWithToken:token];
if (_credential != nil)
{
    self.webMap = [[AGSWebMap alloc]initWithItemId:mapId credential:_credential];
    self.webMap.delegate = self;
    [self.webMap openIntoMapView:self.mapView];
}
```

Here is what I am trying currently:

```
_credential = [[AGSCredential alloc]initWithToken:token referer:nil];
if (_credential != nil)
{
    AGSPortal* portal = [AGSPortal ArcGISOnlineWithLoginRequired:false];
    portal.credential = _credential;
    [portal loadWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
    AGSPortalItem* portalItem = [[AGSPortalItem alloc]initWithPortal:portal itemID:mapId];
    self.webMap = [[AGSMap alloc]initWithItem:portalItem];
    self.mapView.map = self.webMap;
}
```

The problem is if I set the login required to false I get a 400 not logged in error. If I set it to true it pops up a login alert. I think I'm not creating the credential correctly maybe? Like I don't know what to put for the referer specifically. The docs on this are sparse.

Comment: Hello @GBReen, does the error occurs for a shared to everyone service?

Comment: That's a good question. Are there test ones I can use or do I need to create a publicly available service myself to test that?

Comment: Try hosting one and sharing publicly.

Comment: This question is invalid. The error was that the map I was trying to use was too "old". We opened it, resaved it and it started working. Thanks for the help though!